# Local storage variable gets locked in false

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to toggle a true/false variable in local storage.

```
console.log("Toggling...");
console.log("Current:" + localStorage.item);
console.log("Current is being changed to: " + !localStorage.item);
localStorage.item = !localStorage.item;
console.log("Current " + localStorage.item);
```

What this does is this:

First run

```
 Toggling...
    (index):31 Current:undefined
    (index):32 Current is being changed to: true
    (index):34 Current true
```

Second run

```
Toggling...
(index):31 Current:true
(index):32 Current is being changed to: false
(index):34 Current false
```

Subsequent runs...

```
Toggling...
(index):31 Current:false
(index):32 Current is being changed to: false
(index):34 Current false
```

Why does my variable not change back to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your boolean values get stored as a **string** on localStorage.

> **typeof localStorage.item** will return **"string"**

```
> localStorage.item
undefined
> localStorage.item = !localStorage.item
> localStorage.item
"true"
> localStorage.item = !localStorage.item
> localStorage.item
"false"
> localStorage.item = !localStorage.item
> localStorage.item
"false"
```

From this point on, a string with *length > 0* is considered truthy, even if it has the value set to `"false"`.

This also happens if you use the [recommended syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
> localStorage.set('item', true);
> localStorage.get('item');
"true"
```

Consider:

- removing the item from the **localStorage** instead of checking its negative boolean value
- using **JSON.parse()**:

  > localStorage.item = !JSON.parse(localStorage.item)

For additional info, check https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12111

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to directly set properties on `localStorage` like that. Instead, use `setItem(key, value)`, `getItem(key)`, and `removeItem(key)`.

Example from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

> The following snippet accesses the current domain's local Storage object and adds a data item to it using Storage.setItem().
>
> ```
> localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
> ```
>
> The syntax for reading the localStorage item is as follows:
>
> ```
> var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
> ```
>
> The syntax for removing the localStorage item is as follows:
>
> ```
> localStorage.removeItem('myCat');
> ```

So something like this instead:

```
console.log("Toggling...");
console.log("Current:" + localStorage.getItem('item'));
console.log("Current is being changed to: " + !localStorage.getItem('item'));
localStorage.setItem('item', !localStorage.getItem('item'));
console.log("Current " + localStorage.getItem('item'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse() to parse it as boolen value:

```
console.log("Toggling...");
console.log("Current:" + localStorage.item);
console.log("Current is being changed to: " + !JSON.parse(localStorage.item));
localStorage.item = !JSON.parse(localStorage.item);
console.log("Current " + localStorage.item);
```